# How to set size of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, preferredsize

i am trying to set size of JButton, but by default it take whole frame, it's height easily set but i can't set it's width & why its behaving like that i don't know.

my code :

```
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
    btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(32,0));
    ImageIcon icon = new    ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/images_Left.png"));
    btnNewButton.setIcon(icon);
    boxTlacitek.add(btnNewButton);
    getContentPane().add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

any suggestion please ?

Comment: You might find this useful and providing answers to many swing components size/position related questions like this one. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the layout.  Try adding the button to another `JPanel` then add the panel the frame.  `BorderLayout` will stretch the button across the available width of the panel when the component is placed in the `NORTH` or `SOUTH` position

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestBorderLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestBorderLayout();
    }

    public TestBorderLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JButton fat = new JButton("Fat");
                JButton skinny = new JButton("Skinny");

                JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
                buttonPane.add(skinny);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(fat, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it works man, thank you. wonderful support from everyone. awesome one.

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old question but this is bugging me. I was googling the exact problem. Why does adding the button in a JPanel stop it from being stretched? The JPanel is still being added to the SOUTH position of the BorderLayout and everything is essentially the same with the exception of the button being added to the panel first. What gives?

Comment: @Ftahir192 The `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` itself, this means while the `JPanel` is been stretched, the button is not ;)

Comment: Ah right makes sense, thanks. How does one change the layout of the JPanel if they don't favour FlowLayout?

Comment: The same way you change the layout manager for `Container`, `setLayout`.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Answer (score -1):

```
  getContentPane().setLayout(null);
  //setBounds(x,y,width,height)
  btnNewButton.setBounds(10,10,250,100);
  getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

Comment: There are times and places for `null` layouts, IMHO, I don't think this is one of them

Comment: going a step further than @MadProgrammer: whatever the problem, a [null layout is _not_ the solution](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1351374)

Comment: @kleopatra I'm just to nice :P

Comment: @kleopatra  Yes, just read that thread again and smiled.  The tide was going against me until you injected a fresh dose of common sense into the replies.  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you had been #793415 at that time, I probably wouldn't have jumped into the middle of that :-) What happened over there, again?

Comment: @kleopatra  Who can say what happens at the Oracle forums?  I don't visit them anymore, except for reminiscing.  It is a pity the IDs are now missing. :(

Comment: I don't know why the answer by Prabhakaran got voted down, but this is actually the correct answer. Using a null layout gives you COMPLETE CONTROL over the placement and size of controls on your form. It's exactly what I was looking for in fact when I was searching how to manually set the placement and size of things on a Java form. This is the best answer. There's no good reason to let the computer forcefully set the size and locations of controls on a form. That is simply lazy programming for those who don't want to worry about how to programatically arrange the controls on their own forms.